# How can I get Word 2007 to give a correct ending date?

Tags: date, if-statement, ms-word

I'm drafting a lease template using Word 2007 form fields. User will input a start date and how many years the lease will run. Now, I'm needing help in writing the IF statement for the ending date. It needs to follow along the lines of: IF the start date is on the first of the month, then the ending date will be on the first day of the month however many years the lease run is from start, but if the start date is on any other date not the first of the month, then the ending date will be on the last day of the month that the start date was in but however many years the lease run is from start.

So i.e. if the start date was 1/1/2020 and the lease run is 5 years, then the end date should be 1/1/2025. If the start date was 1/2/2020 with the same 5 year lease run, then the end date should be 1/31/2025. Obviously, the formula will have to read actual calendar dates to account for months having 30 or 31 days and Feb. with its 28 or 29 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your formfield is assigned a bookmark named 'StartDate', you could use a formula field coded as:

```
{QUOTE↵
{SET Delay 60}↵
{SET mm{=MOD(ABS({StartDate \@ M}+Delay+11),12)+1}}↵
{SET yy{=INT({StartDate \@ yyyy}+(Delay+{StartDate \@ M}-1)/12)}}↵
{SET dd{=IF({StartDate \@ d}=1,1,IF((mm=2)=1,28+((MOD(yy,4)=0)+(MOD(yy,400)=0)-(MOD(yy,100)=0)),IF((mm=4)+(mm=6)+(mm=9)+(mm=11)+({StartDate \@ d}>1)>1,30,31)))}}↵
"{mm}-{dd}-{yy}" \@ "dddd, MMMM d,  yyyy"}
```

where the number following 'Delay' is the number of *months* to offset. That perhaps makes the field code more complex than it need be, but is also more flexible than working with whole years.

Where the # of *months* is to be supplied by another formfield, you could simply change:

```
{SET Delay 60}
```

to:

```
{SET Delay {Months \# 0}}
```

Where the # of *years* is to be supplied by another formfield, you could simply change:

```
{SET Delay 60}
```

to:

```
{SET Delay {=Years*12 \# 0}}
```

where 'Months' and 'Years' are the formfield bookmark names.

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required. Instead of the ↵ symbols, you should use real line/paragraph breaks.

For a macro to convert the above field code representation into a working field code, see *Convert Text Representations of Fields to Working Fields* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Thank you for that code, it works pretty well. Though I do have one question. Where you have {SET Delay 60}, the number of months will be a user input that will change from lease to lease. So my question is can that Delay number be a user input variable, maybe by REF-ing it or something?